# Angular-material 0.6.1 docs

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp, bower

Does anyone know where I can get the docs for angular-material 0.6.1 I have tried to npm install angular-material-builds@0.6.1, but it does not contain the necessary files to build the documentation for that version. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install with the zip file . You can get the zip file in the following link 
https://github.com/angular/material/archive/v0.6.1.zip

And you will be able to find the updates of this version in the following link

https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#061--2014-12-08